# Submitting an updated value for a read only field

Tags: javascript, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I have a disabled field called `new_limitperiod`, when I change the value to null, and then save the form, the old value comes back on the form.
I've been told to use `setSubmitMode("always")` to solve this problem. 
However when I do that, this causes my plugin to fire every time I update any field, even fields which are not listed in my `FilterAttributes` section for registering the plugin.

How can I submit the new value for my read only field, without it making my update plugin fire every time?:

```
var limitPeriod = Xrm.Page.getControl("new_limitperiod");
limitPeriod.getAttribute().setValue(null);
limitPeriod.setDisabled(true);
limitPeriod.getAttribute().setSubmitMode("always"); //This causes the update plugin to always fire
```

Answer (score 2):

Your approach of setting the field to null and setting the submit mode is correct.

There is no `setSubmitMode` on the control. Instead, you should call `setSubmitMode` on the attribute:

```
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_limitperiod").setSubmitMode("always");
```